# Selected tag of dynamic selection won't work

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following code to display a selection of countries:

```
<div class="col">
    <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" ngModel required>
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries; let i = index" [selected]="country.name.common === 'United States'" [value]="country.name.common">{{country.name.common}}</option>
    </select>
    <img src="/assets/images/icons/chevron-down.svg" alt="Dropdown" class="chevron-icon">
</div>
```

On init the component fetches its data from a JSON file inside of my assets folder. It works - the selection with its countries is being displayed. **How am I able to determine a preselected value.**

As you can see, my approach was to set a `[selected]` with a condition, but it doesn't work. Changing it to solely `[selected]="country.name.common"`, will preselect the list's last country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `ngModel` so  your code should be

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" required>
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries; let i = index" [selected]="country.name.common === 'United States'" [value]="country.name.common">{{country.name.common}}</option>
    </select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnnk1m)

OR

Remove `selected` attr and set `[(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"`  and set in componenet.ts `selectedCountry="countryname"`  [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyh13s)

Comment: How do I adjust my code, in order to keep `ngModel`? Since I pass my data through `ngFrom`.

Comment: @Tim remove `selected` attr and set `[(ngModel)]="selectedCountry"`  and set in componenet.ts `selectedCountry="countryname"`  demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyh13s

Answer (score 0):

In your `component.ts` use the the name for your select and assign it to your desired value like:

```
countries.map((country) => {
if(country.name.common === 'United States') {
// assign here
}
})
```